# What does Õ (omicron tilde) mean in complexity Õ(n) vs O(n)

Tags: math, complexity-theory, big-o

I've never seen this notation for complexity: Õ(n).

It comes up in the context of learning in stochastic algorithms.

Anyone know this notation? You can't exactly google this...

EDIT: SOLVED

I think people have pointed out the right answer below. In my case Õ() is used to hide an exponential growth of a tree.

Comment: Comes up often, or only in a single place? If it's a single place then it might be a spelling error. If it's in more places then it might mean something different from the normal big-O notation used in programming.

Comment: You might be able to google it: "omega tilde notation".  First link is the Wikipedia page on Big-O notation; see the section on [extensions to Bachmann-Landau](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Big_O_notation&section=22#Extensions_to_the_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations), which gives a plausible reading of Õ.  (I don't know enough about the conventions to know if this is the meaning used in your context, so this isn't an answer.)

Comment: Comes up a few times in one paper. It's typeset in LaTeX, so probably no accident.

Comment: Why is this off topic? It came up as a top Google result.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is shorthand for O(g(n) log^k g(n))

Answer (score 12):

Actually, you *can* google this!

It is a variant of big-O that ignores logarithmic factors.  See [this wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%95#Mathematical_use), which I found simply by googling that character and looking at the top entry.