# What is the difference between O(n) and O(n) with tilde

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

I have come across saying that O(n) with tilde hides polylog(n)factors and an additive polylog(n) term.

What exactly these terms mean ?

Answer (score 1):

This would probably mean that there is c > 0 such that f(n) <= n (log n)^c.
Note however that definitions of these kind of things may fluctuate.

Duplicate with [What does Õ (omega tilde) mean in complexity Õ(n) vs O(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744718/what-does-%C3%95-omega-tilde-mean-in-complexity-%C3%95n-vs-on)